# find keys that there exists different values for that key in key, value pairs in Excel

Tags: excel, key-value, conditional-formatting

there are an key value pairs, for example,

```
X 1
Y 2
Z 3
W 1
Z 3
Y 1
X 2
```

I want CF for X,Y because there exist different values.
not W,Z.

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,"<>" & $B1)>0
```

[image]

---

If in the same column:

```
=COUNTIFS($E:$E,"<>" & $E1,$E:$E,LEFT($E1,FIND(" ",$E1)) & "*")>0
```

[image]